# IIS with several bindings i need redirect one to HTTPS

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

We have a website with multiples bindings/domains. I need to redirect one of them to HTTPS. I try some rules with URL Rewrite but it doesnt work:

```
rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^www.domain.com$" />
                             <conditions>
                                 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
                         </rule>
```

OR

```
rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="(.*)" />
                             <conditions>
                                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domain.com$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https:www.domain.com" />
                         </rule>
```

And doesnt work.

Any advise?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine these two rules.

```
rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="(.*)" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domain.com$"/>
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
         </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: You can mark it to help others with same issue.

Comment: i cant, i have not he reputation level